# woocommerce removing images from archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some experience of create wordpress templates...

I have a small woocommerce digital download shop and my client wants to remove the images from right across the site.

I have managed to remove the images on the single product page by adding this into my theme's function.php

```
removeaction( 'woocommercebeforesingleproductsummary', 'woocommerceshowproductimages', 20 );
```

How would I go about removing the images from the archive page? i guess its about finding the right hook but how?

Is there a place where I can find a list of the hooks/filters somewhere please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hook.

```
remove_action(
  'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
  'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail',
  10
);
```

Comment: Fantastic. I knew its was just a question of find the right hook.

Comment: Well you can see all the hooks in the documentation at http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/, But i really hate the woocommerce documentation because it doesn't tell you anything. So the best place to see all the hooks and the functions using these hooks is at https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php. Its a small file and you can have a bird's eye view of all hooks used by woocommerce.

Comment: thanks Omer - really helpful, off to download it for the next little change!